# parsing an ordered JSON response results into an unordered Object

Tags: javascript, json, response

I'm retrieving a JSON response from a server which is already sorted by "sort_id".

responseText ==>

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "complete": 1,
    "list": {
        "178432351": {
            "item_id": "178432351",
            "sort_id": 0,
        },
        "203720680": {
            "item_id": "203720680",
            "sort_id": 1,
        },
        "286082053": {
            "item_id": "286082053",
            "sort_id": 2,
        },
        "284062632": {
            "item_id": "284062632",
            "sort_id": 3,
        },
        "16137955": {
            "item_id": "16137955",
            "sort_id": 4
        }
    },
    "since": 1359248876
}

var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Once I parse it with JSON.parse into an object and then try print the data of each item via

```
for(item in response)
```

The data that get printed are completely unordered. Is there a way to use the "for in" loop by the sort_id order? or any other way to print the received data that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [];  

for(var item in b.list) { 
   var obj = b.list[item]; 
   var elem = {}; 
   for(var prop in obj) {
      elem[prop] = obj[prop];
   } 
  arr.push(elem);
}

arr.sort(function(a,b) { return parseInt(a.sort_id) - parseInt(b.sort_id) } );
```

Comment: Won't that return an array that includes only the IDs?

Comment: @Adonis: No, each `item` is an object.

Comment: `for(item in response.list) { console.debug(typeof item); }`
returns
`(5) string`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript properties are unordered by default, and the order in which they're iterated will not be consistent across javascript engines and implementations.  To have ordered properties you need to have an array.

To sort the properties you can put them into an array, as thikinom's answer suggests.